# VB.NET Word Interop: Add password to open Word document

Tags: vb.net, passwords, office-interop

I am wondering if any of you can help me with this.  I have a web application into which the user puts raw data. It also uses a VB.NET program to create reports based on the data which are them emailed to the user (using Word Interop).

It basically copies a file with the tables in, populates the tables from information in the data base, and attaches the file to the email.

I would like if possible that the user must enter a password to read the document.

In a nutshell, the coding is thus:

```
Public axword As Word.Application
axword = New Word.Application
axword.Visible = False
```

[Procedure for making the unique file name]

[Blank report is copied with the new file name]

```
ThisReport = axword.Documents.Open(fullFileName)
```

[Procedures for making the calculations and populating the tables]

```
 ThisReport.save()
 ThisReport.close()

 axword.Quit()
```

Can anyone tell me how to save it so it needs a password when opened in MS Office Word?

Many thanks

Steve

Comment: [Document.Password property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.password.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I had a look, and I've looked at various of Microsoft's documentation.  I can see it must be possible, but I can't find any clear examples of how to implement it

Comment: The example in the link is more than ample.  Password is a write only String property on the document object  Are you implying that you do not know how to assign a String value to a String Property?